# Exception Access Violation?

Tags: lwjgl

I don't understand, i am learning LWJGL but when i put that code:

```
public void render()
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vID);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * (3 * 4 * 6));

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    }
```

java throw:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000056fda8e0, pid=8840, tid=8336
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_75-b13) (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.75-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [atio6axx.dll+0x21a8e0]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Chargon\Desktop\Programming\JavaRessource\PandorasGame\hs_err_pid8840.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

How can i fix something like that? I enable the client state and the vertexPointer float is '3'. I really need some help x.x Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access violations in LWJGL are mainly caused by buffer sizes and render call counts not fitting.

You should check if your *vID* really holds `CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * (3 * 4 * 6)` elements to draw. See [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml).

My guess is that it that the it should be `CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * (4 * 6)` : CHUNK_SIZE^3 elements with 6 sides consisting of 4 vertices each.

Comment: vID = glGenBuffers();
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vID);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vCoords,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Is cast before the render method

Comment: how many vertices are in this buffer? You most likely are trying to render more than are really in there.

Comment: vCoords = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * (4 * 6)); and after that i flip the vCoords using vCoords.flip(); Ho, and CHUNK_SIZE = 16

Comment: You will have to leave out the `3*`